# Types recognition issue when I import data model from Enterprise Architect to pgAdminIII

Tags: postgresql, database-design, enterprise-architect, pgadmin

I have to implement on Enterprise Architect a GIS model compliant to *Inspire directive*. Then, I have to create the ddl code to insert in postgres to create the physical structure of my db.

The problem is that I don't know what type of diagram I have to set up on enterprise architect.

Now I have created a domain model and imported in my foundation schema the classess directly from the Inspire repository (http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/index.cfm/pageid/2/list/datamodels). I see the issue when I create the ddl and I import this on postgres because postgres does not recognize the Inspire types (eg. CharapterString, GM_Point).

I hope that I did make myself clear.

Comment: I guess this means Enterprise Architect doesn't support Postgres (properly) But `CharapterString` is indeed an invalid data type for Postgres. And `GM_Point` is also not a valid type. Maybe you meant `ST_Point`?  For that you would need to install [PostGIS](http://postgis.net/)

Comment: Well, the DDL generation is run through a script one can modify. And you have to tackle that. It's (like so often) not a diagramming issue (it's never that!) but how to model and tune the tools provided.